# CDT eclipse source code, Disassembly view source code?

Tags: view, eclipse-plugin, export

If disassembly view from CDT eclipse is open source how i can get it? Can that plug in be exported and edited, i need it for my project to see how it works.
Is there entire source of CDT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code is available in the 'SDK' components of CDT.

Select `Help > Install New Software` and enter `http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/8.4` in the 'Work with' field to see all the CDT downloads.

Or you can look at the GIT repositories: http://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git